# I'm left red faced - other expressions?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I know 'I'm left red-faced' means my face gets red. But I'd like to know more expressions to express the same things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Red-faced can mean different things depending on context

As an expression of anger:

- I was left furious / angry / incandescent

After exertion

- I was left exhausted / bushed / done-in

Shamed (this is the most common use)

- I was left embarrassed / blushing / humiliated

Flushed is a good word as an alternative as, like red-faced, it can be used in different contexts

Comment: Here, 'was left' is the same meaning as 'was given a feeling of~', right? I don't get what exactly this means though.

Comment: @jihoon almost... "Was left" infers that the cause has happened, 'was given a feeling of" could refer to something that was continuing.